# How do you let user pick default values for select tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question must have been answered before, but I can't find it anywhere.

I have a form that contains a list of `<select>` options and all of them have defaults that I have chosen. This form is in an overlay, and I want it to act as a settings menu for users. Everything works fine, except for the fact that if you open the overlay, select your options, then close the overlay and open it again, the selects are back to their original default values.

I would like to add an `.onclick` function to the button that closes the overlay that would save the user inputs as the new defaults, but I have no idea how to do this, or even which tag attributes are available for such use.

Also, since I don't have any experience with jquery, I would prefer if the solution used javascript only, unless that is considered bad practice for this type of problem, in which case I will start learning jquery.

Here is a code snippet:

```js
function saveRuleSelections() {
  //add function here to save new default values     
  closeRulesOverlay();
}

function closeRulesOverlay() {
  document.getElementById("rules_overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>Current Rules</h2>
  <p>Number Of Decks:
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6" selected>6</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>Dealer Hits Soft 17:
    <select>
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no" selected>No</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <button id="select_rules_button" onclick="saveRuleSelections()">Select Rules</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add your code here, so that we can work on it!

Answer (score 0):

If it is Javascript, 
Then add "selected" inside the options as an attribute.

```
<option value="options1" selected>Audi</option>
```

[W3School Selected option Example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected)

Comment: Seems like you didn't read the question. I already have defaults, I would like them to change after user makes selections.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onclick function use below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select_rules_button').click(function(){
        //add function here to save new default values                  
        document.getElementById("rules_overlay").style.display = "none";

    });
});
```

Remove onclick function from button control

```
<button id="select_rules_button">Select Rules</button>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `selected` in your HTML code as you

> want it to act as a settings

Hence, you need a variable in your javascript, like `var setting = {numberOfDecks : 6, dealerHitsSoft : "No"};`

When document on ready, use the variable to set default-selected options.
However, setting is better to store in Databases or cookies.

```js
var setting = {numberOfDecks : 6, dealerHitsSoft : "no"};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#numberOfDecks").val(setting.numberOfDecks);
  $("#dealerHitsSoft").val(setting.dealerHitsSoft);

});

function saveRuleSelections() {
  //add function here to save new default values 
  saveSetting(setting);
  closeRulesOverlay();
}

function closeRulesOverlay() {
  document.getElementById("rules_overlay").style.display = "none";
}

function saveSetting(){
   setting.numberOfDecks =  $("#numberOfDecks").val();
  setting.dealerHitsSoft =  $("#dealerHitsSoft").val();
  console.log(setting);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>Current Rules</h2>
  <p>Number Of Decks:
    <select id="numberOfDecks">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>Dealer Hits Soft 17:
    <select id="dealerHitsSoft">
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <button id="select_rules_button" onclick="saveRuleSelections()">Select Rules</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```